# Detect Database Currently in Use with Java

Tags: java, database, jdbc, odbc

Is there a way to detect the ODBC database currently being connected to with Java?
For example, I would like to know whether an application is currently connected to Oracle 10g or SQL Server 2005.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Who is making the connection to the database? Isn't it your application making the connection? So wouldn't you know if you loaded the Oracle or MSSQL configuration?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have `java.sql.Connection` class, `getMetaData` method will return database information. From `DatabaseMetaData` object you can retrieve all kinds of stuff, like driver name or connection url, to determine your kind of server. **edit** There's also `getDatabaseProductName` method there.

Answer (score 1):

Why not extract it from the driver that is in use? IE if your currently using com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, then you know that your using MySQL.

You are passing the driver class name to something, right?

Comment: Often you use frameworks to access Connection object (e.g., application servers manage transactions and connection pools for you, you do not create Connection object yourself there). Not sure what's the case here, though.